# CURL send POST data

Tags: php, curl

I'm using CURL to get response from some webservice. Problem is that it need some POST data in format like this:

```
{
    "type": {
        "manufacturer": "AX",
        "model": "AX",
        "submodel": "AX"
    }
}
```

My script looks like:

```
$url = 'URL';
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

I found a way how to use POST in CURL and it should looks like:

```
$fields = array(
                'manufacturer' => urlencode('AX'),
                'model' => urlencode('AY'),
                'submodel' => urlencode('AZ')
                );
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $fields);
```

But this didn't work for me at all :(, always getting answer NULL. Please can somebody help me to figurate out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: count will send only num of array not the data

Comment: Hi Richie, thanks for answer, you were right. But even if I remove count i get answer NULL

Comment: try with this `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $yourArray)` also check for errors

Comment: Unfortunately same answer as before, NULL. I am thinking if I dont need to send it like JSON format or something. Because API example is in JSON

Comment: If the webservice expecting a JSON string you should provide one, try using `json_encode($fields)` instead of just `$fields`

Comment: Hi Ofir, didn't help. I just try to make this request via POSTMAN GUI and worked well. 
Just open URL with POST and values from top of this question

Comment: There might be something that you are missing like headers or something else. also check for errors

Comment: Right I think i can't write array same as json, because in json there is type and 3 sub values below it (manufacturer, model, submodel) so I think I just dont know to write array like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help, you lead me right way to find solution on this problem.

Problem was in way i Insert json at start which you helped me with, after some googling I found out I miss header `Accept: application/json` as well,

So Final version looks like:

```
$json = '{
    "type": {
        "manufacturer": "AX",
        "model": "AY",
        "submodel": "AZ"
    }
}';
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'WEB';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);

if($response === false){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else{
    print_r($response);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks all and have a nice weekend

Comment: I strongly recommend you use json_encode rather than try to encode the JSON yourself, or you'll quickly get caught by issues with quotes and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Create a sample json like them and try with this. you can get the sample data from postman. As you said you are able to post via postman.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response  = curl_exec($ch);

if($response === false){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else{
    print_r($response);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I really apreaciate your help Richie, but looks my skill is not good enugh, I'm not sure how to create json with some type above manufacturer, submodel, model.
Is there a chance you can write an example?

Comment: that's a different question you should ask a different. If you can create a array like that then `json_encode` will work

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in $data_json.

Full COde: http://pastebin.com/quADrYxe

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually posting data via a POST request or requesting data via a GET request? 
If the latter have a look at Guzzle as it allows you to set a JSON body whereas PHP cURL currently won't. 
Using Guzzle it's as simple as :

```
$request = $guzzleClient->createRequest('GET', $endpoint);
$request->setBody(Stream::factory($jsonQuery));
$response = $guzzleClient->send($oRequest)
```